# Switching between lexical states in javaCC

Tags: netbeans, javacc

I am trying to create a javaCC parser that will behave differently in two code blocks for custom NetBeans plugin, however I cant even recognize two states. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<DEFAULT,STATE1>
SKIP : {
  " " 
| "\t"
| "\n"   
| "\r"
}
TOKEN : {
  < A1: "a"> : STATE1  
}
< STATE1 > TOKEN : {
  < B2: "b" > : DEFAULT
}
```

This simple parser does not parse string "abab..".

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule for "."; so, after parsing "abab", the lexer is stuck.  This is why the error message says 'Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "." (46), after : ""' If you add

```
| "."
```

to the first rule, it will work.